# PHP: make a sign out button in my sign out page

Tags: php

I'm working on a project in PHP and I need help about my sign out page. Currently, my page is like [this](http://prntscr.com/8n3uzg)

So when I click on the sign out button, I'm no longer signed in and I'm redirected to my sign in page. What I would like to do is to create a sign out page with a sign out button to allow the user to have a confirmation message about the sign out. My sign out code:

```
unset($_SESSION["auth"]);
header("Location: sign-in.php");
```

So what I need is when I click on the sign out button (header), I'm redirected to the sign out page with a sign out button (when clicked, I want that the user is no longer signed in).

Answer (score 2):

Alright, as promissed a fully functional script. This will display a button and ask the user to confirm if (s)he wants to logout before actually doing so. You can adept it with other functionality and layouts if you want to.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['logout'])){
    session_destroy();

    #uncomment if you wish to redirect the user somewhere
    //Header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Logout</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
            document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("submit", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                var form = document.getElementById('form');
                var log = confirm("Are you sure you wish to logout?");

                if(log){
                    form.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='logout' value='0' />";
                    form.submit();
                } else {
                    //You could redirect the user away from the
                    //logout page here if you want to or something
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="" id="form" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alright, should be working now. For some reason submitting the form after preventDefault makes it lose the submit button's name. So made a small workaround for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `session_destroy();` to erase session and `header('Location: sign_out.php');` to redirect user to sign_out.php. if you don't want the code after the `header('Location: sign_out.php');` to execute you should use `exit;` right after the header(); function.

**OR** with thanks to icecub:

Use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) session_destroy();`

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that, but what I want is to create directly a sign out page and in this page, create a sign out boutton, you know?

Comment: Simply make a form with just a button and use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ... }` so the php part only triggers after the button is clicked. That's just basic coding @Uptop14

Comment: confirmation?   In that case you can just move session_destroy(); to the confirmation page and execute that if the user confirms.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable That's not even needed. If he wants confirmation, he can simply setup a js event listener, preventdefault, use confirm, submit form or return false.

Comment: I considered JS confirm but i wanted to keep it simple

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable Ghehe in this case, I understand :P

Comment: In my defense, it's a quarter past three o' clock in the morning here. :)

Comment: Nah. I agree with you. Altough those things are easy for us, they can be to complicated for absolute beginners.

Comment: And to complicated/hard for me when it's quite late

Comment: Thanks, @icecub. I'm a beginner and I'm currently learning PHP. I used this: if(isset($_POST['submit'])) and all is ok.

Comment: No problem @Uptop14. I'm actually working on a complete script for you simply because I'm bored. May take a while b4 it's finished though

Comment: Upvoted cause I do think you deserve some credit for this :)